# PHP pagination upside down

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have standard pagination that works well. What I'm trying to do is to have it upside down. So navigation will start from the end. 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 . My limit per page is 15 so I want page nr 1 contain 15 elements and the last page will contain latest elements. I know it is very unusual approach, but that is what I would like to do. But I need someone to put me on the right path and help a bit, please. Thanks.

My funcional code here: (shortened)

```
<?

$adjacents = 4;

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table");
$total_pages = $result->num_rows;
$result->close();

    /* Setup vars for query. */
    $targetpage = "articles";
    $limit = 15;                                
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    if($page) 
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;  
    else
        $start = 0;         

    /* Get data. */
    $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit");


    /* Setup page vars for display. */
    if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
    $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
    $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
    $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1


while($row = $sql->fetch_array())  {

$name = $row['name'];
$ource = $row['source'];

}

?>

<?=$pagination?>
<? $sql->close(); ?>
```

Comment: What is the question here? You can't just give 3 pages of code and ask someone to fix it for you. Start working on it you self and if you face some specific problem ask for help.

Comment: Hi MilanG  - i'm not quite sure how to start? and trully I'm not expecting anyone to fix it for me .. but someone can with one line put me on the right path and save me a lot of time, or show me the logic I don't see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM table");
$total_results = $result->num_rows;
$result->close();

    /* Setup vars for query. */

    $targetpage = "moving-articles";
    $limit = 5; 
    $adjacents = 5;
    $lastpage = ceil($total_results/$limit);                                
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    if( $page) 
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;  
    else
        $start = ($lastpage - 1) * $limit;; 

    /* Get data. */
    $sql = $mysqli->query("(SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY datestamp LIMIT $start, $limit) ORDER BY datestamp DESC");
    if ($page == '') $page = $lastpage; //if no page var is given, default to last page (as first page)
    $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
    $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                          


    /* Draw the pagination object.  */

    $pagination = "";
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "
        <div class='pagination'>";
        /* Next Button */
        if ($page < $lastpage) 
            $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$next/'>« next</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class='disabled'>« next</span>";   

        if ($lastpage < $adjacents * 4) //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
        {   
        /* Backwards Pagination */
        for ($counter = $lastpage; $counter > 0; $counter--) {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$counter/'>$counter</a>";
        }
        }

        else if($lastpage > $adjacents * 4) //enough pages to hide some
        {
            //close to beginning; only hide later pages
            if($page > $lastpage - $adjacents * 2)      
            {

                for ($counter = $lastpage ; $counter > abs(($adjacents * 2) - $lastpage) - 1; $counter--)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$counter/'>$counter</a>";                  
                }

                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/2/'>2</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/1/'>1</a>";

            }
        //in middle; hide some front and some back
            else if($page <= $lastpage - $adjacents * 2 && $page > $adjacents * 2)
            {

                $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$lastpage/'>$lastpage</a>";    
                $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$lpm1/'>$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $page + $adjacents; $counter > $page - $adjacents - 1 ; $counter--)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$counter/'>$counter</a>";                  
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/2/'>2</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/1/'>1</a>";

            }
            //close to end; only hide early pages
            else
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$lastpage/'>$lastpage</a>";    
                $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$lpm1/'>$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = ($adjacents * 2) +1 ; $counter >= 1; $counter--)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$counter/'>$counter</a>";                  
                }
            }

        }


        /* Previous Button */
        if ($page > $counter - 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$prev/'>previous »</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class='disabled'>previous »</span>";

        $pagination.= "</div>";     
    }

?>
```

Comment: If there is any comment or suggestions on this piece of code please let me know

Answer (score 2):

Hmm...first tip - don't use short opening php tags. They are deprecated and can give you problems on some servers.. Start php code with `<?php` .

Second, in your code you have mixed parts that are displaying pager and page content it self. That mySql query is for getting rows of current page. But for pager you will need similar query, which will return just count of all the rows (so without limit part).

```
 $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table");
```

Something like that...

When you get that count number (let's say you have 45 rows total). You have to calculate total number of pages. Which would be like:

```
$pages_number = ceil ($rows_count / $limit );
```

In our case we will have 3 (pages).

Then, you'll need some for loop going backward, from number of pages to 1, something like:

```
for ($i = $pages_number; $i > 1; $i--){
 // write out current link
}
```

This loop will give you numbers 3,2,1...so create links out of them and print them out.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM webelements WHERE web='ALR' AND cat='Article'");
$total_results = $result->num_rows;
$result->close();

    /* Setup vars for query. */
    $targetpage = "moving-articles";
    $limit = 15;                                
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    if($page) 
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;  
    else
        $start = 0;         

    /* Get data. */
    $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM webelements WHERE web='ALR' AND cat='Article' ORDER BY datestamp DESC LIMIT $start, $limit");

    $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
    $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
    $lastpage = ceil($total_results/$limit);    //lastpage  = total results / items per page, rounded up.
    if ($page == 0) $page = $lastpage;          //if no page var is given, default to last page (as first page)
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

    /* Draw the pagination object.  */

    $pagination = "";
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "
        <div class='pagination'>";
        /* Next Button */
        if ($page < $lastpage) 
            $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$next/'>« next</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class='disabled'>« next</span>";   

        /* Backwards Pagination */
        for ($counter = $lastpage; $counter > 0; $counter--) {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$counter/'>$counter</a>";
        }

        /* Previous Button */
        if ($page > $counter - 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$prev/'>previous »</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class='disabled'>previous »</span>";

        $pagination.= "</div>";     
    }
?>
```

Comment: do you have any comments on this one @MilanG?

Comment: About the first query - you don't have to get all the rows and count them....use mysql count function - that's faster. And if rest of the code works then it's fine. :)

Comment: @MilanG, i manage to display navigation backwards, but corresponding records are not correct. I think that has something to do woth $start and $limit values. What do I do wrong?